# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.nullpointerexception newbie code

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm very new to programming and I'm sorry if this type of question has been asked tons of times already. I'm really very new to all this and reading code is still quite confusing to me.

So I've been following some tutorials online and I've managed to create this simple app that adds or subtracts 1 depending on the button pressed.

I've recently picked up how to add a splash screen and learning how activities and intents work.

So I tried adding a splash art before my app starts, but I get an error that crashes the app after the splash art ends. I was wondering if you could help a newbie out. thanks in advance. cheers!

this is the error from logcat

```
09-11 14:02:29.312: D/dalvikvm(3078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 10% free 2676K/2948K, paused 29ms, 
total 31ms
09-11 14:02:29.382: I/dalvikvm-heap(3078): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.189MB for 9830416-byte 
allocation
09-11 14:02:29.422: D/dalvikvm(3078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 12274K/12552K, paused 44ms, 
total 44ms
09-11 14:02:30.202: D/dalvikvm(3078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 12274K/12552K, paused 
26ms, total 26ms
09-11 14:02:30.313: I/dalvikvm-heap(3078): Grow heap (frag case) to 28.857MB for 17479696-byte 
allocation
09-11 14:02:30.432: D/dalvikvm(3078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 29343K/29624K, paused 
117ms, total 117ms
09-11 14:02:31.052: D/gralloc_goldfish(3078): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-11 14:02:34.112: D/AndroidRuntime(3078): Shutting down VM
09-11 14:02:34.124: W/dalvikvm(3078): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
(group=0x41465700)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.testapp.numbercounter/com.testapp.numbercounter.Main}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078):at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(NativeMethod)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter.<init>
(PorterDuffColorFilter.java:28)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setColorFilter(Drawable.java:424)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at 
com.testapp.numbercounter.Main.onCreate(Main.java:26)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at  
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at    
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): at     
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-11 14:02:34.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3078): ... 11 more
09-11 14:02:38.182: I/Process(3078): Sending signal. PID: 3078 SIG: 9
```

Here's the code to the Main.class

```
import android.R.color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

TextView number;
Button add, sub, res;
int counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subBtn);
    res = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resBtn);
    add.getBackground().setColorFilter(color.white, null);
    sub.getBackground().setColorFilter(color.white, null);
    res.getBackground().setColorFilter(color.white, null);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            number.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            number.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

        }
    });

    res.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = 0;
            number.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and here's the code to the SplashActivity.class

```
package com.testapp.numbercounter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle SplashBndl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(SplashBndl);
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            Intent StartPoint = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Main.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(StartPoint);
        }
    }
};
timer.start();
}
 protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     finish();
 }


}
```

and finally my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.testapp.numbercounter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"         
android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.testapp.numbercounter.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

hope someone can help I've been stuck on this problem for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add.getBackground().setColorFilter(color.white, null);
```

You cannot provide a `null` PorterDuff mode (The second argument) when setting the color filter

Specify a porterduff mode and it should work as long as everything else in your code is functional..

```
add.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.white, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); //pick whatever PorterDuff mode is appropriate for you here
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the colorfilter. If all you want is to specify a background color you can just use

```
add.setBackgroundColor(Color.white);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.testapp.numbercounter.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

remove the `<intent-filter`> from the `<activity>` tag..

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with the activity in manifest. This is a null pointer in this line

```
add.getBackground().setColorFilter(color.white, null);
```

check the answer given by dymmeh for more info.